# Why does Alon's combinatorial Nullstellensatz require working over a field.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

In Alon's Nullstellensatz theorems (theorems 1.1 and 1.2 [here](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf)) why is it necessary for $F$ to be a field? As far as I can tell, all the arguments in the proofs should work when $F$ is, say, an integral domain.

Comment: they don't need $F$ to be a field. in theorem 1.1 it is explicitly said that the theorem is true for any subring of $F$ and any integral domain is a subring of it's field of fraction

Comment: obviously he could formulate the theorems better but they are true for any integral domain

Comment: I invite you to look into this article: https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1n14

Answer (score 0):

Here $ F $ is just simply a integral domain. You can use any domain.  Like Ali commented if you take any part of $ F $ or any other integral domain then also the theorem will work.

Like example you have been asked to find the integer whose successor is 6. Many places you will have the equation $ x+1 = 6 $ but we know even if we take the equation as $ y+1=6$ then also nothing will be wrong.

Edit: by any part I mean substring